# How can I enforce uniqueness rules that include more than one table?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

For example, having the tables:

```
Companies (CompanyID)
Workers (WorkerID, CompanyID)
Users (WorkerID, Username)
```

With the correct relationships defined, how do I enforce the predication that **a User's Username is unique in the company where its worker is in**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an indexed view for this

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.EnforceConstraint
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT CompanyID, Username
FROM dbo.Users u 
    JOIN dbo.Workers w ON w.WorkerID = u.WorkerID

GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ix ON dbo.EnforceConstraint(CompanyID, Username)
```

There are certain `SET` options that need to be on for modification of the base tables of indexed views but if you are on SQL Server 2005+ these are on by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly, but you do have a couple options:

1. Denormalize the Users table a bit and add the CompanyID to it.
2. Use an insert/update trigger to do the validation.

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider:

[image]

and to make sure that `WorkerNo` is unique within the company:

```
alter table Workers
add constraint un_co_wrk unique (CompanyID, WorkerNo) ;
```