# Can a multi-field UNIQUE constraint include fields from more than one table?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, join, constraints, unique-constraint

I have the following 2 tables:

```
Bookings
  - User ID

Shifts
  - Booking ID
  - Date
```

I'd like to make sure that a user isn't booked in more than one shift on the same date. In other words, a UNIQUE constraint for fields [Bookings.UserID, Shifts.date]

Can I do this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: How are these tables related?  I see no foreign key relationship explicitly stated.  If you had that it'd possibly be quite simple.

Comment: Shifts.booking_id == Bookings.id. Do I need to specify the relationship explicitly in Postgres? (I'm using Rails, it doesn't normally create Foreign Keys, or things like that, and I'm not really sure what you can/can't do in Postgres). But I'm willing to create it if necessary :-). Thanks!!

Answer (score 8):

**Indexes in PostgreSQL are on *one* table** and cannot span multiple tables.

But you can solve your problem with proper table layout. What you probably need is an n:m relationship, implemented with 3 tables. Then there are various ways to enforce your requirement.

You can store the date in booking redundantly, create the **primary key on `(usr_id, shift_date)`** instead of `(usr_id, shift_id)` and guarantee referential integrity with a *multi-column foreign key* on `(shift_id, shift_date)`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE usr(
  usr_id serial PRIMARY KEY
 --, more?
);

CREATE TABLE shift(
  shift_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, shift_date date
  --, more?
);
```

This also requires a `UNIQUE INDEX` on `shift` first:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX shift_date_idx ON shift (shift_id, shift_date);

CREATE TABLE booking(
  usr_id int REFERENCES usr(usr_id)
, shift_id int
, shift_date date
  --, more?
, CONSTRAINT booking_pkey PRIMARY KEY (usr_id, shift_date)
, CONSTRAINT booking_fkey FOREIGN KEY (shift_id, shift_date)
 REFERENCES shift(shift_id, shift_date)
);
```

Another, less restrictive, but also less reliable way would be a **trigger** `ON INSERT OR UPDATE` on the table `booking` that checks if the user has a shift with the new date already. Could work without the redundant date column.

I would go with the first solution.

---

**There are no indexes on views** in PostgreSQL either.

You *could* create a function that returns `shift_date` for a given `shift_id` and declare it `IMMUTABLE` (although, in fact, it isn't). With that you *could* create a multi-column index on an expression:

```sql
CREATE function f_shift_date (shift_id int)
  RETURNS date
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
$func$
   SELECT shift_date FROM shift WHERE shift_id = $1;
$func$;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX shift_date_idx ON booking (shift_id, f_shift_date(shift_id));
```

This would enforce your condition. But honestly, this is pretty suicidal. The index relies on the condition that you get the same date for a `shift_id` indefinitely. If `shift_date` ever changes relative to its `shift_id`, the index has to be recreated or it will yield incorrect results.
So, *don't do that*.

Comment: Yeah, i'm trying to get away with not having the redundant user_id in my shifts (note, the DB struture you proposed doesn't quite match what I'm using in my original question, but it'll do). I was hoping there was some way to do something like this (which you can in SQL Server): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020190

Comment: I added a bit to my answer. BTW, it's the `shift_date` that is redundant in my example, and you could create the foreign key with `ON UPDATE CASCADE`, so you don't have to worry about having to update `shift_date` in multiple places.

Comment: Ok, i'll just keep enforcing it only on the Model logic, I just wanted to add the extra security, if it was straightforward, but this sounds like it'll bring more problems than it'll solve. Thanks for the info, though, it'll definitely come in handy at some point. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielMagliola When you run into constraints you can't express with foreign keys or unique indexes alone, another useful option in your toolbox is the [trigger function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-trigger.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just the above does not solve your problem?

```
ALTER TABLE shifts
ADD CONSTRAINT uk_shifts_book UNIQUE (booking_id, date);
```

If you already has the referenced column on shifts, then you just need to create an unique constraint (or even an unique index) on the refereced column and the date column.

Comment: I need the combination of user/date to be unique, not booking_id/date